# WCF: IEnumerable implementation on client side with shared servicecontract

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, deserialization, client-side

I have an application that uses WCF for communication with a shared service contract between the client and the service.
For this kind of serviceContract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<string> MyOperation();
}
```

The default implementation of IEnumerable is Array, and I would like to customize the implementation into another one: List, Hashset for example...

My client proxy is not auto generated (so no svcmap file) and I don't want to change IEnumerable for another type in my contract (so as far as I understand WCF deserialization, knowntypes are not working in this case, neither CollectionDataContractAttribute... does it?).

As I have created a RealProxy wrapping channel generation (for recycling management), I can for now intercept the result in it to change the collection type on the fly...

But there is maybe a way to influence somehow deserialization in order to choose the implementation of IEnumerable on client side without creating my own serializer from scratch, or something like that.

Please do not hesitate if my question is not clear enougth of wether my issue is due to a bad approach somewhere.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
Jury Soldatenkov pointed me out a good solution!

Here is my POC allowing to choose IEnumerable implementation:

```
private class CustomDataContractResolver<TCollection> : DataContractResolver where TCollection : class, IEnumerable<object>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Maps a data contract type to an xsi:type name and namespace during serialization.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type to map.</param>
    /// <param name="declaredType">The type declared in the data contract.</param>
    /// <param name="knownTypeResolver">The known type resolver.</param>
    /// <param name="typeName">The xsi:type name.</param>
    /// <param name="typeNamespace">The xsi:type namespace.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if mapping succeeded; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool TryResolveType(Type type, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver, out XmlDictionaryString typeName, out XmlDictionaryString typeNamespace)
    {
        if (declaredType != null 
            && declaredType.IsGenericType 
            && declaredType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        {
            typeName = new XmlDictionary().Add(typeof(IEnumerable<>).Name);
            typeNamespace = new XmlDictionary().Add("custom");
            return true;
        }

        return knownTypeResolver.TryResolveType(type, declaredType, null, out typeName, out typeNamespace);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Maps the specified xsi:type name and namespace to a data contract type during deserialization.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="typeName">The xsi:type name to map.</param>
    /// <param name="typeNamespace">The xsi:type namespace to map.</param>
    /// <param name="declaredType">The type declared in the data contract.</param>
    /// <param name="knownTypeResolver">The known type resolver.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The type the xsi:type name and namespace is mapped to.
    /// </returns>
    public override Type ResolveName(string typeName, string typeNamespace, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
    {
        if (typeNamespace == "custom" 
            && typeName == typeof(IEnumerable<>).Name)
        {
            var argumentType = declaredType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var collectionType = typeof(TCollection).GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(argumentType);
            return collectionType;
        }

        return knownTypeResolver.ResolveName(typeName, typeNamespace, declaredType, null) ?? declaredType;
    }
}
```

I didn't want to change the way the IEnumerable is serialized, but if I don't change IEnumerable serialization, the deserialization method is not invoked for the enumeration.
That's why I choosed "custom" as the namespace in which I should put all my custom stuffs in message... hope this is not a so bad way to proceed...
I guess I also should have used the fullname of the IEnumerable in the name but I have some concerns on the bandwidth in my context.

I use my CustomDataContractResolver this way:

```
private class CustomDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior : DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
{
    [...]

    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, string name, string ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        return new DataContractSerializer(type, [...], new CustomDataContractResolver<HashSet<object>>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try ServiceKnownTypeAttribute?

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I already tried with List<object>, List<string>, it doesn't change anything in my case if the contract still exposes an IEnumerable...

Comment: Interface hasn't any state, it describes behavior. But the only thing you can send via wire is state. This conflict couldn't be fixed easily. The only workaround I could suggest [DataContractResolver](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/06/05/introducing-a-new-datacontractserializer-feature-the-datacontractresolver.aspx). It'll work if both client and server use same .NET libraries.

Comment: Didn't really understood the state things on interface :-) but DataContractResolver was a very good suggestion! I'll update the post with my POC solution. Thanks!